# Nginx How do i route to reverse proxy by location

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Currently i'm using nginx server and using nodejs server as reverse proxy.
I want to make the nginx server proxy_pass different server by location.

So, lets say my domain is `subdomain.domain.com`.

When loading `subdomain.domain.com/`, this should serve static files.

When loading `subdomain.domain.com/example1/req1/req2`, this should route to `127.0.0.1:3000/req1/req2`.

When loading `subdomain.domain.com/example2/req1/req2`, this should route to `127.0.0.1:8080/req1/req2`.

But my configuration routes `subdomain.domain.com/example1/req1/req2` to `127.0.0.1:3000/example1/req1/req2` resulting error. (nodejs returns Cannot GET /example1)

How should I write this nginx conf file properly?

Comment: Any results from `nginx -t`?

Comment: nginx -t test was successful

Comment: If one of the Answers solves your Question, please mark it as such with the check to its left! If you found the answer on your own or with some combination, you can also answer your own question and mark it after 2 days or so! This adds to the body of knowledge and can help you gain reputation on the site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use rewrite directive in location block.

Something like:

```
location /example1/ {
  rewrite     ^/example1/(.*)$ /$1 break;
  proxy_pass  http://xxxxxx;
}
```

You can check documents related to rewrite module at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to add below code snippet to your nginx.conf.

```
    server subdomain.domain.com;
        location / {
            rewrite     ^/example1/(.*)$ /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        }
    }
```